# Sublime Text: "Remove all Folders from Project" Keybinding

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add a keybinding for the menu item "Project > Remove all Folders from Project" in Sublime Text 2 but I can't find the correct command to use.

For "Project > Add Folder to Project..." this worked fine:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+o"], "command": "prompt_add_folder" }`

I've looked in the commands list in `Packages/Default/Default.sublime-commands` but 'remove all folders from project' isn't listed there.

I've tried things like

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "remove_all_folders_from_project" }`
and
`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "prompt_add_folder" }`

but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Default.sublime-commands` contains the commands listed in the Command Palette. To see what commands are associated with which menu items, you need to look in `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`. In this case, the entry is:

```json
{ "command": "close_folder_list", "caption": "Remove all Folders from Project", "mnemonic": "m" },
```

So, your keymapping should be:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "close_folder_list" }
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! didn't know about `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`